# Explicit wait condition using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, wait, webdriverwait, page-factory

Is it possible to pass a IWebElement variable to an explicit wait condition instead of hard coding xpath values? Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to pass grant `Email.GMSName` variable as opposed to hard coding the xpath: `/html/body/table/thead/tr/th[2]`

```
try
{
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
  
    w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(grantEmail.GMSName));

    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.GrantNumber.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.GMSName.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.PIName.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.Institution.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.Title.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.PIReqAmt.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.DIVRecAmount.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.GMSRecAmount.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.GMORecAmount.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.DIVRank.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.RFAPA.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.PCC.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.PercentileScore.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.CouncilNPARS.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.NPARSProgramReqNumberofYears.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.CANPoolcode.Displayed);
    Assert.IsTrue(grantEmail.BatchNumber.Displayed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `IWebElement` object as parameter to `WebDriverWait` `ExpectedConditions`.
Similarly to syntax you presented in the question

```cs
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(grantEmail.GMSName));
```

where you passing a `grantEmail.GMSName` XPath expression.
You can pass a `IWebElement` object, as following:

```cs
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(grantEmailElement);
```

where

```cs
IWebElement grantEmailElement = Driver.findElement(By.XPath(grantEmail.GMSName));
```

[Here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) you can see all the available `ExpectedConditions`.
As you can see, some of them accepting `By` as parameter and others `IWebElement`.